# How to remove white space after parsing from JSON with sed

Tags: linux, shell, sed, json

How can I remove any white space if any after parsing from JSON?

`whereami -r` Parse result without sed.

```
{
  "ip": "95.16.15.10",
  "country_code": "US",
  "country_name": "United States",
  "region_code": "NY",
  "region_name": "New York",
  "city": "The Bronx",
  "zip_code": "10473",
  "time_zone": "America/New_York",
  "latitude": 40.822,
  "longitude": -73.86,
  "metro_code": 501
}
```

Working one but with space.

```
whereami -r | sed -rn 's/(^.*city": ")(.*)(".*$)/\2/p'

The Bronx
```

Sort of working JSON result using `sed -rn 's/(^.*city": ")(.*)(".*$)/\2/;s/ //p'`

```
"ip": "95.16.15.10",
 "country_code": "US",
 "country_name": "United States",
 "region_code": "NY",
 "region_name": "New York",
TheBronx
 "zip_code": "10473",
 "time_zone": "America/New_York",
 "latitude": 40.822,
 "longitude": -73.86,
 "metro_code": 501
```

What I'm trying to accomplished

```
TheBronx
```

Comment: Sure about the "any whitespace"?  Eg. "Los Angeles" => "LosAngeles" ?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk has no problems with that

```
awk  '
    $1 == "\"city\":" {
      $1 = ""
      gsub(/ /,"")
      sub(/^"/,"")
      sub(/",$/,"")
      print
    }
'
```

I'm sure sed can handle it too, but I've never managed its logic.  But have a look on the internet eg. "sed oneliners".

The proof of the pudding is in the eating:

```
$ awk  '
>     $1 == "\"city\":" {
>       $1 = ""
>       gsub(/ /,"")
>       sub(/^"/,"")
>       sub(/",$/,"")
>       print
>     }
> '
{
  "ip": "95.16.15.10",
  "country_code": "US",
  "country_name": "United States",
  "region_code": "NY",
  "region_name": "New York",
  "city": "The Bronx",
  "zip_code": "10473",
  "time_zone": "America/New_York",
  "latitude": 40.822,
  "longitude": -73.86,
  "metro_code": 501
}
TheBronx
```

Comment: awk: cmd. line:1: $1 == "\"city\":" {$1 = "" gsub(/ /,"") sub(/^"/,"") sub(/",$/,"") print }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                   ^ syntax error

Comment: I've added a test run to my answer.

Comment: You're right, I see what my problems was, I'm trying to get this in one single line  to do this location=`sudo whereami -r | awk '$1 == "\"city\":" { $1 = "" gsub(/ /,"") sub(/^"/,"") sub(/",$/,"") print }'   echo'$location'

Comment: Try with ";" at the end of each command.  "echo '$location'" won't work - well, it won't do what you want.  Put $location between double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the sed pattern to replace whitespace.
sed allows chaining patterns.

```
's/(^.*city": ")(.*)(".*$)/\2/;s/ //p'
```

Comment: That does work in a way but it shows the rest of the JSON result that was hidden with 's/(^.*city": ")(.*)(".*$)/\2/p'

Comment: Could you please post a sample json ?

Comment: I modified the post check again.

Answer (score 0):

To extract all values in proper list form to a file using sed.

```bash
sed 's/["{}\]//g' <your_file.json> | sed 's/,/\n/g' >> <your_new_file_to_save>
```

- sed 's/regexp/replacement/g' inputFileName > outputFileName.
- In some versions of sed, the expression must be preceded by -e to indicate that an expression follows.
- The s stands for substitute, while the g stands for global, which means that all matching occurrences in the line would be replaced.
  I've put [  ] inside it as elements that you wanna remove from .json file.
- The pipe character | is used to connect the output from one command to the input of another.
  then last i did substitute "," and add '\n' known as line breaker.

If you want to show a single value see below command:

```bash
sed 's/["{}\]//g' <your_file.json> | sed 's/,/\n/g' | sed 's/<ur_value>//p'
```

For example You wanna extract the value of ip

```bash
sed 's/["{}\]//g' file.json | sed 's/,/\n/g' | sed 's/ip : //p'
```

Result :- 95.16.15.10

- p is run; this is equivalent to /pattern match/! p as per above, i.e., "if the line does not match /pattern match/ , print it". So the complete command prints all the lines from the first occurrence of the pattern to the last line, but suppresses the ones that match.